# How does length effect drag?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, drag

[image]

Section of pipe: 20mm diameter, 2000mm length, hemisphere end cap. Moving horizontally through water, I think that the coefficient of drag would be approx. 0.42.

How would the length of the pipe effect drag?

What if I doubled the length of the body to 4000mm as shown?

Comment: This appears to be a homework question.  https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714/

Comment: Nope. Interested in building something.

Comment: Through the similarity in shape to a torpedo, perhaps you can find some info in declassified military reports like https://apps.dtic.mil/sti/pdfs/ADA056304.pdf, depending on how far you want to dive into the topic (pun intended^^).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a lot of factors impacting the drag equation, so in short, there isn't a short answer.

According to this [Wikipedia link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drag_coefficient#/media/File:14ilf1l.svg), a longer cylinder has a lower drag coefficient than a longer one.

Sidenote:

To get a definite / roughly accurate answer in your case, you would need to look at actual CFD (Computational Fluid Dynamics) simulations to get a better idea, or even better, to do it in real life. CFD is obviously way cheaper and easier to get your hands on.

If you want suggestions, I recommend looking at something like SimScale if you don't have the hardware power, or at Ansys Fluent or Ansys Discovery (you can find student editions online (I only know because I am a student) which will be enough for a simple calculation). It's worth keeping in mind that these simulations are just approximations and aren't completely accurate, and the actual flow is very very intricate and complex, far beyond what even modern computers would be able to do.

This will also lead you to have a much better understanding of how the flow is affected by your components and the effects of it on the rest of your design.

Hope this helped, please do let me know if there is anything else :)